# Random link php

Tags: php, random

I am trying to setup this code that loads a random link but I have one problem:

```
$links = file('myfile.txt');
$rand_link = $links[ mt_rand(0, count($links) - 1) ];
echo '<div class="link"><a href="' . $rand_link . '"><img src="button.png" border="0"></a></div>';
```

It sometimes shows the pages it has shown earlier. I want it to remember what sites it has displayed and don’t show it again until the user starts from the beginning. Thanks appreciate your help.

Comment: I couldn't embed the code there but it looks like this. 
$links = file('myfile.txt'); 
$rand_link = $links[ mt_rand(0, count($links) - 1) ]; 
echo '<div class="link"><a href="' . $rand_link . '"><img src="button.png" border="0"></a></div>';

Answer (score 2):

finally the enhanced version with multiple sites in history

```
// Predefinitions
$links = file('myfile.txt');
$currentPage = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

// make sure links are pure and no whitespaces are left
foreach ( $links as &$link )
{
    $link = trim($link);
}

// prepare for history
if ( ! array_key_exists('visited_links', $_SESSION) )
{
    $_SESSION['visited_links'] = array();
}
// add current site to visited links if it wasnt visited earlier
if ( ! in_array($currentPage, $_SESSION['visited_links']) )
{
    $_SESSION['visited_links'][] = $currentPage; 
}

// get all those links which weren't visited yet kinda $links = $allLinks - $visitedLinks
$potentialLinks = array_diff($links, $_SESSION['visited_links']);

$randomLinkId = mt_rand(0, count($potentialLinks)-1);
$randomLinkIds = array_keys($potentialLinks);
$randomLink = $potentialLinks[$randomLinkIds[$randomLinkId]];


echo '<div class="link"><a href="'.$randomLink.'"><img src="button.png" border="0"></a></div>';
```

there could be potential errors if the format of `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` and this of your linklist differ, you can evaluate this with some quick var_dumps.
As far as I know Wordpress automatically starts an session, this should explain your errormessage. This script assumes that the session is already started.

Comment: unfortunately i am very much beginner. can you help implement this?

Comment: $arrayOFRandomLinks should hold all those links you want to iterate through, you can also do `$arrayOFRandomLinks = include 'somefile.php'` with somefile.php simply being `<?php return array('link1.php', 'link2.php', ...);` 
I added the code to make the rand work, that should be the whole magic

Comment: i just understood that you don't want to show a set of sites, not a single one, for this approach you need to use sessions, i'll implement this too, just give me some time.

Comment: hI Sameul apprecate your time, this seems to be the closest i just faced little error here it says .... Warning: array_key_exists() [function.array-key-exists]: The second argument should be either an array or an object in...

yes the links are external.

Comment: could you give me an excerpt of your myfile.txt so i can test it myself?

Comment: Hi Samuel thanks a lot for the continues help... I still have this error Warning: array_key_exists() [function.array-key-exists]: The second argument should be either an array or an object.  the content of the file are simple links such as http://www.google.com, yahoo, microsoft

Comment: i managed to replicate your error, this means the session hasn't started. try adding `session_start()` at the beginning of your script, it has to be at a place before any output is sent to the browser.

Comment: php has no possibility to read the browser history (as far as i know). if you want i'll add an redirector-script which logs all sites you're sending your users to.

Comment: I have done that but then i experience a lot of Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent ... plz forgive my ignorance.

Comment: i did a quick google on where to start the session. [according to this](http://www.frank-verhoeven.com/using-session-in-wordpress/) you need to add `session_start()` to the `wp-config.php` file.

Comment: I have done that but unfortunately no avail. even i tried outside wordpress but same error.  is there any other mechanism we can achieve this other than this code?

Comment: `if ( ! session_id() ) { session_start(); }` is at the beginning of your config file?

Comment: Yes when I do that the first error disappears but a lot of Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent

Comment: which version of wp are you using?

Comment: stackexchange is a true gift: check this out http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3089/enabling-sessions-in-wordpress-3-0/3090#3090

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. May be errors, I have not tested on the server. And I use the session to preserve already viewed pages.

```
$links = file('myfile.txt');
$show_links = array();

session_start();

if( $_SESSION['show_links'] )
foreach($_SESSION['show_links'] as $key=>$value){
    $show_links[$key] = $value;
}

$random_link_number = mt_rand(0, count($links) - 1);

if(count($show_links) != count($links)){
while(   !in_array($random_link_number, $show_links)   ){
   $random_link_number = mt_rand(0, count($links) - 1);
}
}
else{
    unset($show_links);
}

$show_links[] = $random_link_number;
$_SESSION['show_links'] = $show_links;

$rand_link = $links[ $random_link_number ];
```

Comment: thanks a lot for answer...unfortunately it shows errors like this 

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent 

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded


is there another way we can accomplish this or write this code? thanks appreciate your help.

Comment: nope still experiencing same issue. removed the session_start (); since i am adding this code to a wordpress plugin but still i have the other error.

Comment: But how then you ought to save the data that looked at this site?